# hover is not working on table td

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have 5 `td`'s in a table and, when I hover on it, the background image should change.

Currently, if I hover on 1st or on the last `td`, the background image change but I don't know why this hover effect is not working for other `td`'s.

[image: Image explanation]

**Here's the relevant HTML code:**

```
<div id="main" style="border-bottom-right-radius:0px;border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;" class="shell">
<table border="1" height="100%" width="100%" class="addtasks">
    <tr>
        <td width="20%" class="inboxtasks" align="center" onclick="alert('Comming soon. I am working on this...');"> Past days<br/> <div id="past_days_itemdiv"> 10 </div></td>
        <td width="20%" class="inboxtasks" align="center" onclick="alert('Comming soon. I am working on this...');" > Yesterday<br/> <div id="yesterday_itemdiv"> 10 </div></td>
        <td width="20%" class="inboxtasks" align="center" onclick="alert('Comming soon. I am working on this...');"> Today<br/> <div id="today_itemdiv"> 10 </div></td>
        <td width="20%" class="inboxtasks" align="center" onclick="alert('Comming soon. I am working on this...');"> Tomorrow<br/> <div id="tomarrow_itemdiv"> 10 </div></td>
        <td width="20%" class="inboxtasks" align="center" onclick="alert('Comming soon. I am working on this...');"> Next days<br/> <div id="next_days_itemdiv"> 10 </div></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**And here's the relevant CSS code:**

```
.inboxtasks:hover
{   cursor: pointer;
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    font-size: 14px;
}
.inboxtasks{
    height:80px; 
}
```

**Update:**

In a simple html page it's working, but my application is big, with **lots** of html code, then I don't know what's the reason for this problem.

**Full code (really big)** : http://jsfiddle.net/Rd2v4/

Comment: It seems to work fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/Ng655/

Comment: Code is all set, working fine for me also

Comment: yes it is working for me as well

Comment: Works fine http://jsfiddle.net/nXfZW/

Comment: clear your browser cache.might be the reason that css in not uploaded correctly.!

Comment: @Adrift yeah in simple html page its working, but my application is bigger with lots of html code, i don know what can be reason?

Comment: @KamleshArya i tried your suggestion, but still same problem

Comment: what browser you using?

Comment: You need to do the basic debugging, isolating the problem so that you can post code that actually reproduces (unless you already found a solution in the process). We cannot do that for you, since we have no access to your code.

Comment: @jhyap chrome,  mozilla

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela  Till then i will do those work, i guess i can solve it by myself

Comment: your code is not big, but is too messy for us to check.

Comment: @jhyap yes i agree what you said. its done by juniors, i actually do not have enough time to format the entire html code.

Comment: The link does not point to the full code. It contains references to style sheets on your disk. And really, the SO way is that you do the debugging, removing errors that you can fix, isolating the problems, ending up with a constructive question demonstrated with *minimal* code that reproduces an issue, if some unsolved issues remain.

Comment: You "*[don't] have enough time to format the entire html code*" but expect us to debug it for you?

Comment: We do not have enough time to debug your problem too. Try to do something like what I suggested. Put all the relevant `style` into `css` first and format it out. Is a practice.

Comment: @jhyap I removed entire html code, i am again creating a new template for them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

:hover is a pseudo-selector, and everything beginning with : is such (e.g. :active, :before etc.).

This can be confused with specifying values:

something: value;
So you need to think about pseudo-selectors as separate objects, not a value.

That's why you need to fix your td: hover so it looks like td:hover.

Note that if you put a space after td like so:

```
td :hover { ...
```

This is equal to:

```
td: *:hover { ...
```

and therefore will select all items descending from td and apply a style on hover to them (see this example).

Remember, spaces have a meaning in CSS.

Comment: `:hover` is a *pseudo-class*, which is itself a (real) selector; `:before` and `:after` (properly `::before` and `::after`) are psuedo-*elements*.

Answer (score 1):

As what other people said, your `html` and `css` works fine for me too.

If your problem still persist. You can try restart your browser and clear your `cookies/cache`.

Your `html` can be improved by setting all the `style` within the `css`

```
.inboxtasks:hover
{   cursor: pointer;
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-align: center;
}
.inboxtasks{
    height:80px; 
    width:20%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: without <style> tag, i never write css .. i update my question